# How to add multiple BooleanBinding to single button?

Tags: button, javafx, boolean

I need to make multiple bindings and address them to the same button.
Right now I have this `BooleanBinding`:

```
        BooleanBinding even = new BooleanBinding() {
        { super.bind(plaintextHex.textProperty()); }

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return ((plaintextHex.getText().length() % 2) != 0);
        }
    };
```

And this one:

```
        BooleanBinding maxS = new BooleanBinding() {
        { super.bind(keyHex.textProperty()); }

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return (keyHex.getText().length() > 32);
        }
    };
```

If I want to assign one `BooleanBinding` it looks like this: `crButton.disableProperty().bind(even);`, but if I want to assgin muttiple I can't find any info on how to do it. The idea was that it would look something like this: `crButton.disableProperty().bind(even, maxS);`, but of course it doesn't work like that. Do I have to make both in the same `BooleanBinding` or there is a method to combine them?

Comment: What do you mean by "bind multiple"? You want it disabled if either one of the boolean bindings is true? If both are true?

Comment: You cannot bind a property to multiple expressions, since binding is basically *"keep the value of this property the same as this other expression"* which will not work, if there are multiple expressions that possibly contain different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you need, you can do

```
crButton.disableProperty().bind(even.or(maxS));
```

or

```
crButton.disableProperty().bind(even.and(maxS));
```

Or you can just create a single binding:

```
BooleanBinding maxSOrEven = new BooleanBinding() {
    { super.bind(keyHex.textProperty(), plaintextHex.textProperty()); }

    @Override
    protected boolean computeValue() {
        return keyHex.getText().length() > 32 || plaintextHex.getText().length() % 2 != 0 ;
    }
};

crButton.disableProperty().bind(maxSOrEven);
```

etc.